# Microsoft Bot Framework, Login with Office 365

Tags: c#, botframework, office365api

I am new in this Bot Framework, I have failed to find enough help on the internet regarding login 365 Authentication.

I have developed a simple Card ordering Bot, Now I need to authenticate it with Office365 account. I have followed this AuthDemo (https://github.com/tsmatsuz/AuthDemoBot)

After clicking Connect on Emulator I have this link :

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https:%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2F&client_id=18ab0821-0bbc-4d05-9f65-a30e34f3faa3&response_type=code&haschrome=1&redirect_uri=https:%2F%2Fauthdemoweb.azurewebsites.net%2FHome%2FAuthorize&x-client-SKU=PCL.Desktop&x-client-Ver=3.13.4.878&x-client-CPU=x64&x-client-OS=Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.2.9200.0

Which crashes.

Regarding our application

1. I have created an app on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList
   AppID :     df0a8a77-708e-443b-88af-41eb6bXXXXXXX
2. I have added this appID in webConfig of our project.
3. My BOT is not yet approved and we dont have **BOTID** and
   **BOTSECRET**.
4. I have hosted my BOT Code and Login API on our server with SSL
   implementation. (Code is copied from AuthDemo but Keys are changed)

When I run My code on IIS, It make a link https://msbot.devbatch.com/web/Home/Login?userid=2c1c7fa3
And I get this error :

> Sign In
>
> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. We received a bad
>   request. Additional technical information: Correlation ID:
>   a462bfbb-c932-4078-bf8b-b3bbe9dbd78e Timestamp: 2016-10-25 05:36:11Z
>   AADSTS65005: The client application has requested access to resource
>   'https://outlook.office365.com/'. This request has failed because the
>   client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess
>   list.

I need complete configuration/Steps on Sign in via Office365.

Comment: You don't need to have your bot approved to have a bot id and bot secret. And this part of error should help: This request has failed because the client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list.

Comment: @K48 What it means by adding this resource in requiredResourceAccessList ? and which resource to add?

Comment: How can i have bot id and bot secret without BOT approved by Review board.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OAuth integration with O365 fails with error AADSTS65005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093954/oauth-integration-with-o365-fails-with-error-aadsts65005)

Answer (score 2):

AuthBot creator here. The error you're getting essentially means that when you registered your application Azure Active Directory you didn't specify in the permissions that you need access to outlook.office365.com.

Comment: is there an alternative source for this video?